# Eclipses: no consoles to display at this time

Tags: bash, java, eclipse, programming, ide

How do I get a `bash` terminal [or](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11112670/262852) console from within `Eclipse` itself?

[image: opening]

but no prompt:

[image: no_bash]

I just see:

`no consoles to display at this time`

"Window->Show View->Other". Search for Terminal and select "Open". Click on "Open a Terminal" icon as demonstrated here and choose Local Terminal.

But I only see "console":

[image: menu]

which gives me something without a `bash` console.

Comment: Go to "Window->Show View->Other". Search for Terminal and select "Open". Click on "Open a Terminal" icon as demonstrated [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnbp2.png) and choose Local Terminal. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I don't see an option for `Local Terminal` -- are you sure @Kulfy?

Comment: aha, I think i'ts this "tm terminal" from the marketplace

Comment: Nope. It's not there in General Views. Scroll down, you'll find a separate section for Terminal. You can refer [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTCjh.png)

Comment: thanks, got it @Kulfy -- although I don't know it that "tm terminal" was necessary or not.  I could remove it and see.

Comment: In 2020 tm Terminal became a part of Eclipse project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Console is for [Standard streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams). It's not a terminal. The terminal in Eclipse is provided by [TM Terminal](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/tm-terminal) which became a part of Eclipse CDT Project. It is more likely to be preinstalled in the installation. If it isn't, you can install it from the marketplace.

To open a terminal in Eclipse, you either take the long road or shorter road.

- #### Long Road:

  Go to **Window**→**Show View**→**Other**. Search for Terminal which is probably under Terminal section instead of General. Select Terminal and press **Open**.

  You'll see Termial view at the bottom or on left depending on preferences. Click on the left most blue **Open a new Terminal** icon on the left side of the view panel.

  [image]
- #### Shorter Road

  - Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and select Local Terminal.

    If you want to open a terminal in the directory of some project or package, click on the project/package before hitting the key combinations.
  - Alternatively, right click on any project/package and click on **Show in**→**Terminal**.