# how to source bashrc from the eclipse terminal?

Tags: bash, java, eclipse, bashrc, ide

How do I [configure eclipse](https://askubuntu.com/q/1249082/45156) so that I have access to `bash` complete with my aliases?  I ran:

```
[org.eclipse.Java ~]$ alias
[org.eclipse.Java ~]$ source /home/thufir/.bashrc
```

but that seems awkward.  Also:

```
[�� org.eclipse.Java ~]$ 
[�� org.eclipse.Java ~]$ echo $SHELL
/bin/sh
[�� org.eclipse.Java ~]$
```

wheras `gnome terminal` gives:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
thufir@dur:~$
```

Comment: what does *echo $SHELL* say

Comment: you've hit the nail on the head, @bac0n -- it's not loading a ?bash? config script?

Comment: The prompt of the terminal also seems different. What is the output of `whoami` and `pwd`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44220993/how-to-run-system-shell-terminal-inside-eclipse/44220994  picture suggests bash is an alternative to the eclipse terminal

Comment: you may try: *SHELL=/bin/bash ./eclipse* and check again if eclipse honor shell env